# Undesired space beetwen equations

Tags: align, matrices

I want to write four equations: One in the top left `A_f=...`, other in top right `B_f=...`, other in bottom left `C_f=...` and the fourth in the bottom right `D_f=...`.

The equation `A_f=...` should be aligned with the equation `C_f=...` and the equation  `B_f=...` should be aligned with `D_f=...`.

The code below produces the desired alignement, but I'm having an undesired space beetween the equation (see picture). How can I solve this?[image]

Code:

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}

 \usepackage{amsmath}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{align*}
  A_f&=
  \begin{bmatrix}
 -10.6448 &  14.7778 \\
 -0.3811  & -1.5941
  \end{bmatrix}
  &B_f&=\begin{bmatrix}
  0.0962 \\
  2.3280 
  \end{bmatrix} \\
  C_f&=\begin{bmatrix}
  -1.0000 & 2000
  \end{bmatrix}
  &D_f&=-1.6607 
  \end{align*}
  \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `alignat`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

 \usepackage{amsmath}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{alignat*}{2}
  A_f &=
  \begin{bmatrix}
   -10.6448 &  14.7778 \\
   -0.3811  & -1.5941
   \end{bmatrix} & \quad
   B_f&=\begin{bmatrix}
   0.0962 \\
   2.3280 
  \end{bmatrix} \\
   C_f&=\begin{bmatrix}
  -1.0000 & 2000
  \end{bmatrix} &
   D_f&=-1.6607 
  \end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```